# While inserting values i need to remove the last comma from the date and save in insert procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

```
CREATE procedure [dbo].[usp_insertleavedetails]                  
 @Emp_id int ,                
 @Rec_Name varchar(50) ,                
 @CompanyName varchar(30) ,            
 @Month_Year varchar(9),           
 @Task varchar(20) ,       
 @RemainingDaysofLeave varchar(2),               
 @NoOfDaysLeavTakn varchar(12) ,                
 @NoOfAvailblLeav varchar ,                
 @LossofPay varchar(2) ,             
 @LeaveTakndates varchar(200),               
 @TtlLeavTakn varchar(12)                           

AS                          
BEGIN                                          
Insert into tbl_Leavetbl(Emp_id,Rec_Name,CompanyName,Month_Year,Task,RemainingDaysofLeave,NoOfDaysLeavTakn ,NoOfAvailblLeav ,LossofPay ,LeaveTakndates,TtlLeavTakn)                
Values(@Emp_id ,@Rec_Name,@CompanyName,@Month_Year,@Task,@RemainingDaysofLeave,@NoOfDaysLeavTakn,@NoOfAvailblLeav,@LossofPay,(SELECT LEFT(Leavetakndates,CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(',',Leavetakndates)>0 THEN LEN(Leavetakndates)-1 ELSE LEN(Leavetakndates) END) FROM tbl_Leavetbl),@TtlLeavTakn)                
END
```

This is the insert procedure i used,In 'LeaveTakndates' this field am inserting date values seperated with comma.I need to remove the last comma.

Comment: provide sample data

Answer (score 0):

without knowing sample data,its hard to guess your logic ,you can do this to remove last comma

```
left((SELECT LEFT(Leavetakndates,CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(',',Leavetakndates)>0 THEN LEN(Leavetakndates)-1 ELSE LEN(Leavetakndates) END),len((SELECT LEFT(Leavetakndates,CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(',',Leavetakndates)>0 THEN LEN(Leavetakndates)-1 ELSE LEN(Leavetakndates) END))-1)
```

below is some example to give you some idea..

```
declare @string varchar(max)='a,b,c,'
select left(@string,len(@string)-1)
```

**output:**
a,b,c

Comment: 08/09/2016,08/17/2016,  sample data will be like this and i need to use this in the insert sp